# Slow send message to SQS using Lambda with low memory

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We have created some sample lambdas to test SQS insertion performance.
At first we used 128MB lambdas and got 40ms average for insertions of 7KBytes packages.
When we upgraded the lambda to 256MB we got 20ms averages and when we upgraded to 512MB we even got 11ms average time for insertion.

We wanted to know why the bigger memory/cpu of the lambda gets better insertion speeds on SQS, because we thought sqs insertion should not be related to memory or CPU capacity. In summary: Is there any operation inside the sqs client send operation that requires good CPU/Memory to perform better?

Thanks!

Here is our test code:
public class Function
    {

```
    public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var client = new AmazonSQSClient();

        var request = new SendMessageRequest
        {
            MessageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>(),

            MessageBody = "7kbyte String here...",
            QueueUrl = "https://our_account/sqs-test-queue  "
        };

       //Just desconsidering the first 2 sent messages, to desconsider the initial connection overhead 
        var elapsed00 = await SendMessageResponse(client, request, -2);
        var elapsed0 = await SendMessageResponse(client, request, -1);

        double totalTime = 0;
        const int totalIterations = 1000;
        for (int j = 0; j < totalIterations; j++)
        {
            var elapsed = await SendMessageResponse(client, request, j);
            totalTime += elapsed;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("$$$$$AVERAGE:" + ((double)(totalTime / totalIterations)));

        return "End test";
    }

    private  async Task<long> SendMessageResponse(AmazonSQSClient client, SendMessageRequest request, int i)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var response = await client.SendMessageAsync(request);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        //Console.WriteLine("&&&#####" + i + "Elapsed ms:" + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + ". For message ID '" +
          //                response.MessageId + "':");
        i++;
        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting discovery! Didn't think it would have *that* much impact. See my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQS isn't behaving differently in relation to your lambda size, the code which you're running in Lambda is changing it's performance based on the memory/CPU allotted.

Comment: We are not saying SQS is behaving differently, but we want to understand why the sending of the message to SQS would be CPU intensive enough to be faster with increase of CPU? The lambda code we use is basically performing the delivery of the messages to SQS, so where is the CPU involved?. We though the sending of the message would represent a bigger impact in network IO and not in CPU/Memory. Unless sending of the message using the amazon SDK performs some operations that require more CPU power than establishing the network connections and transport.

Comment: CPU would mostly be involved in serializing/signing the message for transport over http, parsing the response. Any retries would also impact this (though probably not in your situation). You also may want to consider using the SendMessageBatch API if you have a lot of messages to send